# Add product price in required currency

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore, currency

There are two store views in the site - for EUR and USD. But when creating or editing a product you can set price only on EUR.
Is there a way to set product price in USD also?

Answer (score 0):

From store view, you cannot get set store_view wise product price.

You should create two different Website for two store view.

- ***Website Euro ->store view Euro***
- ***Website USD ->store view USD***

Comment: I created 2 websites, but it shows same currency in product form anyway, despite switching between websites

Comment: You need change website base currency